# main.cpp не видит заголовочный файл

Tags: c++, visual-studio, компоновщик

Наверное глупый вопрос, извините уж) Ну или видит его, и проблема в чем-то другом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

math.h

```
#ifndef MATH_H
#define MATH_H

int getSquareSides()
{
    return 4;
}

#endif
```

geometry.h

```
#include "math.h"
```

Буду очень благодарен за любые рекомендации и помощь.

Comment: Пробовали перезапустить `Visaul Studio`?

Comment: Нет, сейчас попробую

Comment: Вообще-то здесь принято код, сообщения об ошибках и т.п. давать текстом; скриншоты - не более чем дополнение, но не основной источник информации...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я думаю вы добавили в папку `"Исходные файлы"` сначала файл `geometry.cpp`, а потом переименовали его в `geometry.h`. Т.к. я воспроизвел у себя такую же ситуацию и получаю такие же ошибки.

Это происходит потому, что когда вы создаете `.cpp` файл, то ему в `Visual Studio` присваивается тип `"Компилятор С/С++"`

Чтобы исправить эти ошибки:

1. Можно удалить полностью файл `geometry.h` и сразу создавайте файл, как "Файл заголовка" (`.h`).
2. Щелкнуть правой кнопкой по нему, потом `Свойства` и изменить тип на `"Заголовок C/C++"`

Ну и лучше все таки создавать его в папке `"Файлы заголовков"`, хотя роли не играет особо.

Comment: Достаточно просто щелкнуть на нем правой кнопкой мыши, выбрать "Свойства", и указать тип - "Заголовок С/С++". Ну, а потом неплохо бы перетащить его в папку "Файлы заголовков".

Comment: Да я знаю, уже отредактировал ответ

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, помогло, Большое спасибо, буду теперь знать.

Answer (score 4):

Ваша проблема в том, что `geometry.h` в вашем проекте - *исходный **компилируемый** файл*, а не файл заголовка (см. правую часть скриншота). Кстати, текст ошибки недвусмысленно указывает на существование `geometry.obj`.

Вот вы и компилируете и получаете одну и ту же функцию в двух объектных файлах, и компоновщик оказывается в роли буриданова ишака, не понимая, какую же из функций выбрать...

Comment: Хмм странно. Я сделал все в точности как у автора вопроса и у меня нет никаких ошибок.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков И вы вставили `geometry.h` в проект как **исходный файл**? Который компилируется и дает `geometry.obj`? Внимательно посмотрите на правую часть скриншота - заголовочный только `main.h`, **но не** `geometry.h`.

Comment: Автор вопроса добавил сначала `geometry.cpp` а потом просто переименовал?

Comment: Да у меня так же в "Исходные файлы" лежит `geometry.h` Просто я добавлял его изначально как файл заголовка, а не исходный файл

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Как именно он это сделал - я не знаю, но это не важно, важен результат. У вас генерируется `geometry.obj`?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Можете на нем щелкнуть правой кнопкой и изменить тип на "Компилятор С++" (сделал в VC++ 2017, получил аналогичную проблему).